# Update ngModel only after successful input validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have the following input defined

```html
    <input
      id="xInputControl"
      name="xInputControl"
      type="text"
      xInput
      class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="x"
      #validated="ngModel"
      (ngModelChange)="valueChanged()"
    />
```

and the following custom validator

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[xInput]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: LatestXInputValidatorDirective,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class LatestXInputValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (
      control.value === undefined ||
      control.value === null ||
      control.value === ''
    ) {
      return { emptyInput: 'dummy text' };
    } else if (
      control.value.indexOf(',') > 0 ||
      control.value.indexOf('.') > 0
    ) {
      return { decimalNumber: control.value };
    } else {
      const parsed = parseInt(control.value);
      if (isNaN(parsed)) return { notANumber: control.value };
      else if (parsed > 200) return { overLimits: control.value };
      else if (parsed < 1) return { negativeNumber: control.value };
      else if (parsed === 1) return { useLatestAggregation: control.value };
      // this the case where the result is valid
      else return null;
    }
  }
}
```

based on [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

> The value of ngModel won't be set unless it passes validation for the input field. For example: inputs of type email must have a value in the form of user@domain

also [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#model-updates-and-validation)

> The default behaviour in ngModel is that the model value is set to undefined when the validation determines that the value is invalid.

So I would expect that the `ngModelChange` method defined in the html input to be invoked only when the input passes the validation.

Unfortunately this is NOT the case. The `(ngModelChange)="valueChanged()` gets invoked every time I type something. I know this because this is the method

```js
  valueChanged() {
    console.warn('x is ', this.x);
    ...
  }
```

I see logs on the console upon every keystroke

How can I make the `valueChanged` get invoked only if the input has a VALID value - passes the `LatestXInputValidatorDirective` validation ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest to not use the dual binding approach. If you have the two-way binding with [()] syntax (also known as ‘banana-box syntax’), the value in the UI always syncs back to a domain model in your class.

```
[(ngModel)]="x"
```

Your html should look more like that

```
<form #it="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(it, $event)>
  <input
  type="text"
  id="xInputControl"
  name="xInputControl"
  class="form-control"
  ngModel
  #xInputControl="ngModel"
  xInput/>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!it.valid">
   submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I do not have the option of creating a form though. It should be just a single input.

Comment: it is just a way to demo validations but your main issue is you are using the dual binding [()], this will always update your model from UI